# Buffering/Updating issue for text element

Tags: perl, tkx

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Tkx;

my $mw = Tkx::widget->new('.');

$mw->g_wm_minsize( 400, 350 );

my $btn_start = $mw->new_ttk__button( -text => "Start", -width => 60, -command => sub { start(); } );

my $txt_processed_domains = $mw->new_tk__text( -width => 40, -height => 10, -state => "disabled", -wrap => "none" );

Tkx::grid( $btn_start, -row => 2, -columnspan => 3, -padx => 10, -pady => 10 );

Tkx::grid( $txt_processed_domains, -row => 3, -columnspan => 3, -padx => 10, -pady => 10 );

Tkx::MainLoop();

sub start {

    foreach my $id ( 1.. 10 ) {

        $txt_processed_domains->configure(-state => "normal");
        $txt_processed_domains->insert_end( "$id => Available\n" );
        $txt_processed_domains->configure(-state => "disabled");

        sleep 1;
    }

    Tkx::tk___messageBox( -message => "Completed!" );
}
```

I need to see which ids are processed but only get whole list at the end. It's like buffering with filehandles but i'm not sure. How to see text in the text box just after inserting it?

Comment: Please move your answer into [the answer box below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583038#post-form) since this question still shows up as unanswered in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find `Tkx::update();` do what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Tkx::update_idletasks() would be the preferred call in this case.